# Can someone explain why sizeof() returns these values with unary operators?

Tags: c, operators, sizeof, unary-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    char b;
    short int c;
    double d;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b), sizeof(c), sizeof(d));
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", sizeof(+a), sizeof(+b), sizeof(+c), sizeof(+d));
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", sizeof(-a), sizeof(-b), sizeof(-c), sizeof(-d));
    return 0;
}
```

32-bit compiler output:

```
4 1 2 8
4 4 4 8
4 4 4 8
```

The output is the same if I change the the sign inside the `sizeof()`, like `sizeof(-a)`. I want to know why this happens. Are the `+` and `-` operators promoting the datatypes?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the unary `+` and `-` operators integer promote small integer types to `int`. C17 6.5.3.3:

> The result of the unary + operator is the value of its (promoted) operand. The integer
> promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

> The result of the unary - operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer
> promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

For details about integer promotion, see [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

---

You can play around with `_Generic` to find out the actual type of any expression:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define type(x) _Generic((x),    \
  int:   puts(#x " is int"),     \
  short: puts(#x " is short"),   \
  char:  puts(#x " is char") );  \

int main (void)
{
  int a;
  char b;
  short int c;
  
  type(a); type(+a);
  type(b); type(+b);
  type(c); type(+c);
}
```

Output:

```
a is int
+a is int
b is char
+b is int
c is short
+c is int
```

Comment: You might also mention that `%d` expect an `int` value, whereas `sizeof()` has type `size_t`, potentially incompatible with `int`.

Comment: @chqrlie Does it matter in practice? I suspect there are very few real cases where `%d` would cause incorrect behavior and `%zu` would save the day, long as we stick below `INT_MAX`.

Comment: It depends on the ABI. 64-bit arguments could be passed via different registers than 32-bit arguments, or use different amounts of stack space, which would make the mistake have unexpected behavior. I am not sure the current ABIs for Linux, Windows and OS/X pose such a problem problem, but I would not be surprised if passing enough 64-bit arguments where `printf` expects 32-bit integers cause unexpected behavior, and I am not willing to take chances.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly it. When calculations are made (i.e. for instance + or -) the shorter integer formats are [promoted](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) to the base size, which is int, which is 4 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

Small integers types are promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` when used as arguments in simple arithmetic expressions. Hence `sizeof(b)` is `1`, the size of a `char`, but `sizeof(+b)` is `4`, the size of an `int` on your platform.

Note however that `printf` expects an `int` argument for the `%d` conversion specification. `sizeof()` has type `size_t`, an unsigned type potentially different from `unsigned int`. You should either use `%zu` or cast the `sizeof()` expressions as `(int)`.

Here is a sample program for illustration:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define typeof(X)  _Generic((X),                                        \
                   long double: "long double",                          \
                   double: "double",                                    \
                   float: "float",                                      \
                   unsigned long long int: "unsigned long long int",    \
                   long long int: "long long int",                      \
                   unsigned long int: "unsigned long int",              \
                   long int: "long int",                                \
                   unsigned int: "unsigned int",                        \
                   int: "int",                                          \
                   unsigned short: "unsigned short",                    \
                   short: "short",                                      \
                   unsigned char: "unsigned char",                      \
                   signed char: "signed char",                          \
                   char: "char",                                        \
                   bool: "bool",                                        \
                   __int128_t: "__int128_t",                            \
                   __uint128_t: "__uint128_t",                          \
                   default: "other")

int main() {
    int a;
    char b;
    short int c;

#define TEST(x)  printf("%8s has type %s and size %zu\n", #x, typeof(x), sizeof(x))
    TEST(a);
    TEST(+a);
    TEST(b);
    TEST(+b);
    TEST(c);
    TEST(+c);
    TEST('0');
    TEST(*"");
    TEST(0);
    TEST(0L);
    TEST(0LL);
    TEST(0.F);
    TEST(0.);
    TEST(0.L);
    TEST(sizeof(a));

    return 0;
}
```

Output on 64-bit OS/X:

```
       a has type int and size 4
      +a has type int and size 4
       b has type char and size 1
      +b has type int and size 4
       c has type short and size 2
      +c has type int and size 4
     '0' has type int and size 4
     *"" has type char and size 1
       0 has type int and size 4
      0L has type long int and size 8
     0LL has type long long int and size 8
     0.F has type float and size 4
      0. has type double and size 8
     0.L has type long double and size 16
sizeof(a) has type unsigned long int and size 8
```

Comment: Re “except as arguments to `sizeof()` or `_Alignof()`”: And except as an argument for a parameter with a type, a controlling expression of a `_Generic`, an operand for parentheses, an operand of `+` or `-` with a pointer, the operand of an increment or decrement operator, the operand of a cast, the right operand of a simple assignment, or the operand of a comma operator.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree that reality is more subtle... I amended the answer and tried to keep it simple.